# Save view in another viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

My problem is...
I've UIView class where I've two methods( method which create 10 buttons and method which create a custom label...I've another ParentViewController class and childViewController of him...
In ParentViewController storyboard i create View on him, add custom class of my UIView, and outlet in ParentViewController...
In Parent ViewController i need hide my view and in child i need to show, but when i test and invoke view in ParentViewController i have only whiteColor window of view.
P.S. View must displayed custom label on top and 10 buttons below...

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet myUIViewClass *uiViewClass; // My Outlet from UIView to ParentVieController      
// In viewDidLoad of ParentVC.

[self buttonsMethod] // UIViewClass method of buttons
[self labelMethod] // UIViewClass method of label
[self.view addSubView:self.uiViewClass] //
```

All is very simple but have a problem...

Comment: you would be better if answered the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big problem is in your this code

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet myUIViewClass *uiViewClass;
```

Just remove IBOutlet from your code.

Then this code in the ViewDidLoad of your implementation (.m) file

```
uiViewClass= [[myUIViewClass alloc]init];
[self.view addSubView:uiViewClass];
```

Hopefully it will work for you

Comment: Thanks I faced the same problem and it is solved with this code

Comment: Thats great keep it up

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to understand. Therefore my answer may be way off.

If you really need to hassle around with parent and child view controllers, which I doubt, then your child view controller should provide methods for your parent view controller which will then access its UI elements and hide and unhide them.